# How to use a list of lens?

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

Can I use a list of Traversal? The following code:

```
f::[Int] -> [[Int]]
f l = [l & i .~ 1 |  i<-[ix 0], (l^? i) == Just 0]
```

produces an error:

```
  • Couldn't match type ‘Const (Data.Monoid.First Int) [Int]’
                     with ‘Identity [Int]’
      Expected type: ASetter [Int] [Int] Int Integer
        Actual type: Getting (Data.Monoid.First Int) [Int] Int
    • In the first argument of ‘(.~)’, namely ‘i’
      In the second argument of ‘(&)’, namely ‘i .~ 1’
      In the expression: l & i .~ 1
```

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816019/pass-a-lens-into-a-funciton) I think I need somehow to explicitly give a type to i, but every my attempt fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in specifying type explicitly. Every time you want to have a container of lenses or traversals (lens inside pair, lens inside list, lens inside `Maybe`) you need to use [`ReifiedLens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedLens).

See this question for explanation:

[Why do we need Control.Lens.Reified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088563/why-do-we-need-control-lens-reified)

So your example should be written like this:

```
import Control.Lens

f :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
f l = [ l & i .~ 1 
      | Traversal i <- [Traversal $ ix 0]
      , l ^? i == Just 0
      ]
```

> Note that here `Traversal` is a constructor of type `ReifiedTraversal`.

And it works like this:

```
ghci> f [0,0,0]
[[1,0,0]]
```